# HMRC VAT API Invalid_Date_Range

Tags: api, date, delphi

I am trying to use the Delphi TREST components to connect to the HRMC VAT API.

I have got as far as obtaining access and refresh tokens, but I cannot get any further.

At the moment, I am trying to retrieve my obligations as follows:-

```
RESTClient := TRestClient.Create('https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/organisations/vat/666596898/obligations');
try
    RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(RESTClient);
    RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(RESTClient);
    OAuth2 := TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(RESTClient);

    with OAuth2 do
        begin
            AccessToken := <my access token>;
            ResponseType := TOAuth2ResponseType(rtCODE);
            TokenType := TOAuth2TokenType(ttBEARER);
        end;

    with RESTClient do
        begin
            Authenticator := OAuth2;
            ContentType := 'application/json';
        end;

    with RESTRequest do
        begin
            Client := RESTClient;
            Response := RESTResponse;
            Accept := 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json';
            Params.AddItem('from', '2017-01-25', pkGETorPOST);
            Params.AddItem('to', '2017-01-25', pkGETorPOST);
            Execute;
        end;

    finally
      RESTClient.DisposeOf;
    end;
```

This particular code returns the error INVALID_DATE_RANGE.  But depending on what dates I use, I also sometimes get CLIENT_OR_AGENT_NOT_AUTHORISED.

Can anyone shed any light on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it doesn't like the start and end dates being the same? It does say invalid date RANGE rather than invalid dates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that is not the problem.  I tried lots of different dates, and different ranges.  If I don't add the parameters, I get INVALID_DATE_FROM / INVALID_DATE_TO as applicable.  And it throws different errors for invalid date formats.  So it appears to be recognising the date parameters correctly, but then objects to the range.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out finally.  It was a problem with my Test User credentials.  I generated them from the HMRC website, but I discovered from other posts that there is a problem generating them that way.  When I created a user via the API, it works fine!

I hope this helps someone.